# How to make sure that performSegueWithIdentifier() gets executed only once?

Tags: ios, swift

When tapping on a button I perform a network call and on successful response I execute performSegueWithIdentifier() to navigate to the next view controller. But sometimes the user taps the button multiple times since there can be a delay before getting the response from the network.

How to make sure that performSegueWithIdentifier() gets executed only once?

Or would there be a better approach to disable the user interface until receiving the response from the net?

...I've tried to identify the "current" view controller using the `presentedViewController` and `presentingViewController`, but looks like my understanding is wrong, as I couldn't make any use out of it.

Here's a snippet I've created to isolate and replicate the problem (my view controllers are embedded in navigation controller):

```
// MARK: - Actions
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    delay(3.0) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("seg", sender: nil)
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("seg", sender: nil)
}

// MARK: - Helper
func delay(delay: Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Comment: could you create a bool property on the view controller that is set to true when the request is in progress so it doesn't make the request again? Why do you have a 3 second delay? that snippet would cause it to be executed twice as well

Comment: Yes, I've added a bool property. It works fine. That snippets simulate the double calling of `performSegueWithIdentifier()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the button, but the race condition will still exist.  What you need is a bool property that you can set the first time in.   Then you simply add an "if (alreadyPressed_) return" to the top of the method.  Of course you have to set it when the button gets pressed and you have to figure out when it is safe to clear it allow the button to be pressed again.

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet can be used as reference. You can press the button as many times as you like but after delay the segue will be performed only once. The `delay()` function is just to simulate the waiting for completion of network call described in the question on top.

```
var loginInProgress = false

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard !loginInProgress else { return }
    loginInProgress = true
    delay(3.0) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("seg", sender: nil)
        self.loginInProgress = false
    }
}


// MARK: - Helper
func delay(delay: Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```